# How I can get the difference by time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, time, timespan

i want to calculate a checktime to the time now and get the hours.

I have a string "time" for example...

```
string t1 = UserParam[12].ToString(); // "9/26"
string t2 = UserParam[13].ToString(); // "14:51\r"
```

I need them in my Project where I get from the License Server the time from a user and I want to show the difference to now. I want show this in hours.

I want a time how ---> 1 hour(s), 49 minute(s)

Comment: Why is `UserParam[12].ToString()` returning two different values? And furthermore, what's the actual type of `UserParam[12]`? If it's a `DateTime` already, you probably should use it like that rather than calling `ToString()`.

Comment: use DateTime.TryParse, DateTime.UtcNow, put the difference in a TimeSpan and use TimeSpan.TotalHours

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do. Please supply more information.

Comment: please refer http://forums.asp.net/t/1908140.aspx?Find+time+difference+between+01+30pm+to+11+30pm+Using+c+net

Comment: I mean UserParam[12] and UserParam[13] ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume `t1` is the month and date and `t2` is the hour and minute.

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
string t1 = "9/26";
string t2 = "14:51";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(string.Format("{0} {1}", t1, t2), "M/dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now - dt;
double totalHours = diff.TotalHours;  // 0.726172292194444
```

**Edit**:

> I get a error --> not the right format

Maybe because you have unwanted characters at the end of the string(s) as in `"14:51\r"`. You can use `Trim` or `TrimEnd` to remove them. For example:

```
string t2 = UserParam[13].ToString().TrimEnd(new []{ '\r', '\n' }); // 14:51
```

Comment: Since you warnt the hour and minutes use TimeSpan.Hour and TimeSpan.Minute instead of TotalHours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`DateTime.Subtract`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8ysw4sby.aspx) to calculate the difference between dates and times:

```
string date = "9/26 14:51";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "M/dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt);
```

Comment: Did you mean [DateTime.Subtract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want your times in `DateTime` structures.  If you have timestamp information in a string, then you should use [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e.aspx) to fill a `DateTime`.  But if you have the timestamp in a string it will be important to *specify time zone info in the style parameter* (`DateTimeStyles`).

Then you can take make a `TimeSpan` by subtracting two `DateTime` stucts  and use the `TotalHours` property

```
(dt1 - dt2).TotalHours
```